# Facebook API - Upload 360 deg Photo 500 Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-graph-api, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a Spherical Image to Facebook from S3. by doing the following

```
begin
    @client.put_picture("https://s3.amazonaws.com/skreem-dev/PANO_20160717_120803_1.jpg", { allow_spherical_photo: true })  
rescue Exception => e  
    print e.inspect
end
```

It returns the following Error Message

```
#<Koala::Facebook::ServerError: type: OAuthException, code: 1, message: An unknown error has occurred. [HTTP 500]>
```

It works with any normal images from the same `s3 bucket`

** **UPDATE 1** **

Tried to upload the same image from `Godaddy` and i am facing the same issue.

** **UPDATE 2** **
Tried to upload via Graphy API Explorer, but getting the same error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1,
    "fbtrace_id": "CWqqwQ3WBq+"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you set up the Bucket policy and CORS for the Bucket from where you are sharing the Image?

Comment: @error2007s okay. this is something new. can you please point me to something i can read about this

Comment: You said normal images are showing but not the spherical so I guess the issue is different here I was checking out this guide of setup but not sure the Policy and CORS is issue, if that was issue the images will not show up at all. http://ivrpa.org/news/hosting-360-vr-panoramas-on-amazon-web-services-s3/

Comment: @error2007s yeah :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your almost 15Mb image is too large. The error you are getting from Koala is not that accurate, you can try to upload it from the Facebook API explorer `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer` and see.

Also, check the token you're using, as this is throwing an OAuth error. It could be expired.

Comment: How can i upload photo from the explorer?

Comment: First get an access token and select permissions. You can click on the `GET TOKEN` button. After this you can select a `POST`action and have a look to the Facebook API docs to see how your request should be. Sorry but it's a long time since I don't use this API and I don't know the exact request for the current version.

Comment: So, everything indicates that the image is too large. Can you try with another one?

Comment: I can upload the same image if the image is in localhost :(

Comment: Interesting... Did you try to configure the timeout options of Koala? As seen here: https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/HTTP-Services

Comment: @CV-Gale any idea where i can set it. Read through that part not able to understand how to set it

Comment: I'd do it in config/initializers/koala.rb